# cURL not accepting sftp

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, sftp

I am trying to setup SFTP with cURL and I followed these instructions on [Andrew Berls' blog](http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/adding-sftp-support-to-curl), but if I run the command `curl -V` I get this output:

```
curl 7.57.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2017-11-29
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

So for some reason sftp is not showing up, how can I fix this?

This is the error log when I run `make install` following the instructions above:

```
Making install in lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/curl-7.47.0/lib'
  CC       vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo
vtls/openssl.c: In function 'Curl_ossl_cleanup':
vtls/openssl.c:758:3: warning: 'ERR_remove_thread_state' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ui.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/engine.h:29,
                 from ../lib/urldata.h:88,
                 from vtls/openssl.c:41:
/usr/include/openssl/err.h:247:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(void ERR_remove_thread_state(void *))
 ^
vtls/openssl.c: In function 'verifyhost':
vtls/openssl.c:1095:9: warning: 'ASN1_STRING_data' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         const char *altptr = (char *)ASN1_STRING_data(check->d.ia5);
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50,
                 from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
                 from vtls/openssl.c:41:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:553:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
 ^
vtls/openssl.c:1178:15: warning: 'ASN1_STRING_data' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               memcpy(peer_CN, ASN1_STRING_data(tmp), j);
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50,
                 from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
                 from vtls/openssl.c:41:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:553:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
 ^
vtls/openssl.c: In function 'get_cert_chain':
vtls/openssl.c:2353:29: warning: passing argument 1 of 'X509_get0_signature' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         X509_get0_signature(&psig, &palg, x);
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50:0,
                 from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
                 from vtls/openssl.c:41:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:552:6: note: expected 'const ASN1_BIT_STRING ** {aka const struct asn1_string_st **}' but argument is of type 'ASN1_BIT_STRING ** {aka struct asn1_string_st **}'
 void X509_get0_signature(const ASN1_BIT_STRING **psig,
      ^
vtls/openssl.c:2353:36: warning: passing argument 2 of 'X509_get0_signature' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         X509_get0_signature(&psig, &palg, x);
                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50:0,
                 from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
                 from vtls/openssl.c:41:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:552:6: note: expected 'const X509_ALGOR ** {aka const struct X509_algor_st **}' but argument is of type 'X509_ALGOR ** {aka struct X509_algor_st **}'
 void X509_get0_signature(const ASN1_BIT_STRING **psig,
      ^
vtls/openssl.c:2360:27: warning: passing argument 3 of 'X509V3_ext' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
       X509V3_ext(data, i, X509_get0_extensions(x));
                           ^
vtls/openssl.c:2246:12: note: expected 'struct stack_st_X509_EXTENSION *' but argument is of type 'const struct stack_st_X509_EXTENSION *'
 static int X509V3_ext(struct SessionHandle *data,
            ^
vtls/openssl.c:2389:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'EVP_PKEY {aka struct evp_pkey_st}'
       switch(pubkey->type) {
                    ^
Makefile:1868: recipe for target 'vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/curl-7.47.0/lib'
Makefile:880: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: If you run `sudo ldconfig` before doing the make commands does that help?   Remember to run the `make clean` before rerunning the make commands.

Comment: @Terrance unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

On the [link you provided](http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/adding-sftp-support-to-curl), according to the very first comment curl needs to be installed from source with the `--disabled-shared` ran with the `./configure` command:

First, get the curl source:

```
apt source curl
```

Then go to the curl folder: *(this folder could be different depending on version downloaded)*

```
cd curl-7.47.0/
```

You might need to reinstall the `libcurl-openssl` libraries before running the next part:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then run the `configure` command:

```
curl-7.47.0$ CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
curl-7.47.0$ LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib"
curl-7.47.0$ LIBS="-ldl"
curl-7.47.0$ ./configure --disable-shared
```

Then run the `make` and `make install` commands:

```
curl-7.47.0$ make
curl-7.47.0$ sudo make install
```

Then curl should now show the `sftp` protocol:

```
curl-7.47.0$ curl -V
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.5.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting this error on running the `make install` command `vtls/openssl.c:2389:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'EVP_PKEY {aka struct evp_pkey_st}'
       switch(pubkey->type) {
                    ^
Makefile:1868: recipe for target 'vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/curl-7.47.0/lib'
Makefile:880: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed`

Comment: would I need to uninstall cURL before reinstalling it?

Comment: @HarryCameron I didn't have to uninstall first.  I followed Step 1 on that site then Step 2, but the Step 2 made no difference.  So from my source folder, I made the install clean `make clean` then I reran through the steps in my answer.

Comment: even if I try the `make clean` command then I reran through the steps from your answer but got the same error

Comment: @HarryCameron Try running this before doing it:  `sudo apt install --reinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: I still get the same error, so I ran the above command, then `make clean` within the curl-7.47.0 folder, then I ran `./configure --disable-shared` then `make` and the error popped up

Comment: @HarryCameron Looks like on this page https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1583 that they were getting the same error.  So, before the configure they typed in all 3 of these lines:  `CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include \` , `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib" \` , `LIBS="-ldl" \`  I can't get the editing here right.  I will add those to the answer.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the full log I get after running `make install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71683/discussion-between-harry-cameron-and-terrance).

Comment: @HarryCameron I am actually no longer of help here as I cannot duplicate your issue that you are having.  Everything I have thrown your way I am googling to find from here on out.  I will not be any help in chat.  It doesn't sound like it is an issue with curl itself but more with the libraries and how they are installed.  I am able to follow through those steps on two different computers and they have worked for me.

Comment: I now have the SFTP protocol installed as it shows up when I run `curl -V` but I still cant upload files to my server using cURL

Comment: A few notes: I had to run `apt-get install libssh2-1-dev`.  When I ran the configure command, I had to also use the `--with-libssh2` option.  Finally, after running `make install`, it places the `curl` file in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @Teddy Good find!  It has been a while since I touched this, but that is awesome info for the newer version of curl.  Just ran it and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!  =)