# cURL sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: 16.04, server, ftp, sftp, curl

I am trying to use sftp with cURL to upload files to my webserver, if I run `curl -V` on my server I get this output

```
curl 7.47.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp scp sftp smtp telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

But if I try to upload files to my server using sftp:// for the `curl` URL I get this output after adding the `-v` option to the curl command:

```
* Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
curl: (1) Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

To install cURL with the SFTP protocol I used these instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/995820/778003).

Comment: Please provide the exact commands you are running.

Comment: @fkraiem, did, `curl -V` is the command I ran on the server

Comment: Solved in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128780/how-to-build-the-latest-curl-from-sources-to-allow-downloading-files-via-sftp/1128781#1128781