# curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_cleanup

Tags: 18.04, curl

When I type `curl -v` I get this error:

```
curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_cleanup
```

I removed curl and reinstalled it, but the same error appeared.

Comment: Did you build curl yourself, from source? perhaps this is related: [How to build the latest curl from sources to allow downloading files via sftp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128780/how-to-build-the-latest-curl-from-sources-to-allow-downloading-files-via-sftp)

Comment: Look at `ldd $(type -p curl)`

Answer (score 6):

Run `sudo ldconfig`, it solves "curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_cleanup"

From : https://mysiar.github.io/devops/2020/04/23/curl-from-src.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try the snap version of `curl`:

```
sudo snap install curl
```